# Getting Bad request error when I do a username/password OAuth request

Tags: oauth2

I get an error when I do a username/password OAuth request through Java application.I get a error response of {"error":"unknown_error","error_description":"retry your request"}

Below is the code:

```
static final String USERNAME     = "vs@ag.com";
        static final String PASSWORD     = "vs12345FNIysElOWUiApVnBjVDNIPQF";
        static final String LOGINURL     = "https://test.salesforce.com";
        static final String GRANTSERVICE = "/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password";
        static final String CLIENTID     = "3MVG9Z8h6iuu0zc7GGsuiuFM8.PmmE6cJHb_HRxc4vyVIRqi8n4Cn.zLOs260Kkiu9Da9p1Q_9zXYhvpvgui9";
        static final String CLIENTSECRET = "8889001773333222111";

System.setProperty("proxyHost", "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx");
            System.setProperty("proxyPort", "8085");
           // HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();  //without proxy
            HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("xxx.xx.xxx.xxx", 8085);
            DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner =  new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
            HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRoutePlanner(routePlanner).build();
            // Assemble the login request URL
            String loginURL = LOGINURL +
                              GRANTSERVICE +
                              "&client_id=" + CLIENTID +
                              "&client_secret=" + CLIENTSECRET +
                              "&username=" + USERNAME +
                              "&password=" + PASSWORD;
            System.out.println("login URL"+loginURL);
            // Login requests must be POSTs
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(loginURL);
            //httpPost.addHeader("content-type", contentType);
            HttpResponse response = null;

            try {
                // Execute the login POST request
                response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                System.out.println("response--- "+ response.getStatusLine());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException cpException) {
                cpException.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I tried using sandbox domain url as well instead of test.salesforce.com but that is also not working.

None of the solutions provided for the similar questions is helpful to me. So please don't mark this question as duplicate.

Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct security token?

Comment: that can be related to TLS 1.0., try to print response.getEntity(), refer to [link](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000221207)